# Получить местное время пользователя в сообщение боту в Телеграме

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, timezone

Бот пишется на телеботе, но суть в самом API Телеграма.

В полученном сообщении от пользователя есть атрибут date с unix временем, но нет ничего, что бы указывало на временную зону или метки UTC +00XX.

Есть ли способ узнать местное время пользователя без нужды дополнительно спрашивать его о часовом поясе? Нужно это все, чтобы бот не слал ему сообщения ночью. Может я что-то фундаментальное упускаю.

Чтобы далеко не ходить: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message атрибуты для message

Comment: Вроде нет такого в API. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871426/telegram-bot-get-user-timezone

Comment: Спасибо. Значит и правда нельзя.